# How to implement mixed mode authentication using Asp.Net Web API2 and AngularJs application?

Tags: angularjs, web, webapi2

I've a requirement of using mixed mode authentication in my projects which uses WEB API2 (Service) and AngularJs (UI) as technology stack. 
I've found a no of articles exploring mixed mode authentication but all were using web application. Can we implement the same via WEB API2?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Define mixed mode authentication.